# How comment_set.all is used to get data from model where it doen't exist?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

In the HTML comment_set.all is used to get data from model where it doesn't exist. What is the concept behind this.

**post_detail.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
...
<div>
        {{ instance.comment_set.all }}
</div>
...
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[<Comment: User_Name >]
```

Codes that supporting this

Comments app model is given below

**comments/models.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
from posts.models import Post

class Comment(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    post        = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    content     = models.TextField()
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.user.username)
```

**posts/models.py**

```
...
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, 
            null=True, 
            blank=True, 
            width_field="width_field", 
            height_field="height_field")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content = models.TextField()
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    objects = PostManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp", "-updated"]

    def get_markdown(self):
        content = self.content
        markdown_text = markdown(content)
        return mark_safe(markdown_text)
...
```

**posts/views.py**

```
...
def post_detail(request, slug=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if instance.publish > timezone.now().date() or instance.draft:
        if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
            raise Http404
    share_string = quote_plus(instance.content)
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "share_string": share_string,
    }
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)
...
```

Note in the views.py the posts_detail.html is rendered through post_detail() 
but, in the posts_detail.html we are accessing data of comments in it. How this is possible, since there is no foreign key in posts/models.py to the  Comment in comments/models.py

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't exist? And the foreign key is from comment to post.

Comment: post  = models.ForeignKey(Post) this field is present in Comment model but in the case of Post model there it don't have any foreign key for comments that are specific to that post. Still the comments are accessed from the post_detail.html ,rendered by view that is linked by Post model.

Comment: This field is what?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to access the `Comment`s from the `Post` because Django automatically adds an attribute to the `Post` model called `comment_set` so that the foreign key relationship can be followed backwards.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

> **Following relationships “backward”**
>
> If a model has a ForeignKey, instances of the foreign-key model will
>   have access to a Manager that returns all instances of the first
>   model. By default, this Manager is named FOO_set, where FOO is the
>   source model name, lowercased. This Manager returns QuerySets, which
>   can be filtered and manipulated as described in the “Retrieving
>   objects” section above.